# Check does file exist java.nio

Tags: java, filesystems, java.nio.file

I'm trying to check does file exist but it doesn't work.

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getDefault();
Path p = fs.getPath(fileName);

if(!Files.exists(p)) {
    create(fileName);
} else {
    throw new ConflictException(String.format("File already exist."));
}
```

The problem is that even the file exist with same fileName it goes inside `if statement` and goes to `create` method and when it came to part to create file then it returns exception that file already exists.
What could be the problem and possible solution to check does file/directory exists if I'm using FileSystem?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong.

The general principle when working in environments subject to external change, such as file systems, you **just cannot do check-and-act**. That entire principle is **broken** in such an environment, and you're doing it here:

You check if the file exists, and then depending on the result of that, you choose an action. That's **check-and-act** and doesn't work.

After all, what if the 'answer' to your check changes in between the check and the act? It doesn't even have to be another thread within your own VM, it can be another process. You can't synchronize on anything to get this job done 'safely' either.

No, the right principle is **act-then-check**. Do the operation 'make this file but only if it is not already there', atomically, and deal with the fallout, that is, deal with the error afterwards if the file already existed.

Java's nio has support for this, fortunately (the old File API does not, don't use that). Lastly, there is no need to go via the FileSystem stuff, not as long as you are using the default filesystem. However, if that was just there for the purposes of simplifying the question, this works just as well with a custom filesystem:

```
Path p = Paths.get(fileName);

try {
    try (var out = Files.newOutputStream(p, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW)) {
       // write your file here
    }
} catch (FileAlreadyExistsException e) {
    throw new ConflictException(String.format("File already exists", e);
}
// CREATE_NEW is the magic voodoo here: That tells java:
// do this ONLY if you make a new file, otherwise don't do it, atomically.
```

though note that FAEException is fine as is, so I'm not sure you should neccessarily wrap that into a conflictexception - that only makes sense if this API has abstracted away the notion that you are doing this thing to the filesystem (you did not include a method name or javadoc in your paste, so I can't tell).

If you don't need to write anything to the file, you don't need `newOutputStream`, you can just go with:

```
Path p = Paths.get(fileName);

try {
    Files.createFile(p);
} catch (FileAlreadyExistsException e) {
    throw new ConflictException(String.format("File already exists", e);
}
// Files.createFile implies CREATE_NEW already; it either makes
// the file and returns, or doesn't and throws FAEEx.
```

Comment: Do we know that other processes may be creating the files?  If it is only kavkax’s program that creates them, an atomic check isn’t going to solve the problem.

Comment: @VGR ... but it would solve the problem. check-then-act works fine in situation A and fails in situation B. act-then-check works fine in A and also works fine in B, which makes it strictly superior. (A = there are no other processes messing with the filesystem AND no other threads, B = there are other processes and/or threads that may create that file).

Comment: For context, it sounds like perhaps kavkax's problem is more related to e.g. having the wrong filename in the first place. However, there is little point helping someone debug code that is fundamentally incapable of doing the job it is intended to do; better to first at least set it up so that it can at least do the job it is meant to do, and THEN if there are still issues after the rewrite, fix them.